# Loading AWS sdk in chrome extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome-extension, amazon-cognito

In my chrome extension, I was trying to load the AWS Cognito js SDK in the popup type iframe HTML where the HTML is bundled by react, now the problem is I am not able to access AWS instance or ( window.AWS ) in my useEffect to perform user authentication

PS: I tried to get the window object too like below but it was hard luck.

```js
chrome.tabs.query(
      {active: true, windowType: 'normal', currentWindow: true},
      function (d) {
        chrome.tabs.get(d[0].id, function (tab) {
          chrome.windows.get(tab.windowId, function (win) {
            console.log('App -> win', win)
            debugger // THIS IS THE WINDOW OBJECT
          })
        })
      },
    )
```

from background_script.js I get a trigger for on click extension icon

```js
function gotMessage(payload) {
  if (payload.message === 'SIGNAL_TAB') {
    iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('./index.html')
    document.body.appendChild(iframe)

    toggle()
  }
}
```

In Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.831.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my App.js

```js
function App() { 
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('App -> window.AWS', window)
    chrome.tabs.query(
      {active: true, windowType: 'normal', currentWindow: true},
      function (d) {
      console.log("App -> d", d)
        chrome.tabs.get(d[0].id, function (tab) {
          chrome.windows.get(tab.windowId, function (win) {
            console.log('App -> win', win)
          })
        })
      },
    )
    return <SomeJSX />

}
```

Here is my index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Elixir AI",
  "description": "Elixir AI description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "bookmarks", "unlimitedStorage", "storage",  "http://*/", "https://*/"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["./content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["index.html"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["./background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "elixir.png"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-Vkb/pSN52JgiWSIfh1wav6XGzM3ULeZ5d9VaHeA5JQ8='; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Background.js

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked)
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
  let url = tabs[0].url
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    window.linkedin_url = url
    localStorage.setItem('linkedin_url', url)
    res(url)
  })
})

function buttonClicked(tab) {
  var payload = {
    id: tab.id,
    tabs: chrome.tabs,
    eventTab: tab,
    message: "SIGNAL_TAB",
    linkedin_url: tab.url
  }
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, payload)
}
```

Comment: `chrome.windows` does not return a browser `window` object, it's a completely [different thing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window). Show us the code that loads the popup/iframe and indicate the place where you load the SDK and where you want to use it.

Comment: Hey, i have updated my description. thank you so much for helping me out

Comment: Show how app.js and background script are loaded/declared, for example your manifest.json.

Comment: yeah app.js is loading from index.js I have shared the entire file  in the description.

Comment: `window.AWS` should be directly accessible in app.js, no need for chrome.tabs.query and any other `chrome` methods, but you may need to add `https://sdk.amazonaws.com` to `content_security_policy` in manifest.json

Comment: I have consoled the window.AWS but no luck it's printing undefined

Comment: I can't help further so the only thing you can do is debug the code in devtools and check the network panel to make sure the script is loading and there are no CSP errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your efforts, we ll keep posted here if I can able to pull it off